# How do you filter a list based on matching items in another list?

Tags: linq

I have an Organisation object

```
public class Organisation
{
    OrgId {get....}
    OrgName {get...}
    AccountTypes { get....} //this is of type List<AccountType>
}
```

and an AccountType object

```
public class AccountType
{
    AccountTypeId {get....}
    AccountTypeName {get...}
}
```

I'm looking for a way to look through the existing Organisations List and remove AccountTypes from each organisation where the account types are not found in another list of AccountTypes (which would be a post back from a browser).

Would I do something like?

```
var foundOrgs = from org in orgs
                where org.OrganisationId == Convert.ToInt32(hash["orgId"])
                select org;
Organisation organisation = foundOrgs.ElementAt(0);
organisation.AccountTypes.Clear();
organisation.AccountTypes = // What goes here?
```

I'm looking to do a Linq query that will compare one list with another and return only those items where the AccountTypeIDs match, or are present.

Comment: check my latested edited code hope this works for you , if it works dont forget to upvote and mark answer as accepted ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx):

```
// where accounts is IEnumerable<int>
organisation.AccountTypes.RemoveAll(at => !accounts.Contains(at.AccountTypeId));
```

Answer (score 1):

### EDITED CODE

```
//created account id list over here
var AccountTypeID = accountType.Select(x=>x. AccountTypeId);

//you code    
var foundOrgs = from org in orgs
                 where org.OrganisationId == Convert.ToInt32(hash["orgId"])
                 select org;
 Organisation organisation = foundOrgs.ElementAt(0);
 organisation.AccountTypes.Clear();
//changes in code where you want to change -// What goes here? 
List<AccountTypes> templist = organisation.AccountTypes;
 organisation.AccountTypes = 
               from acc in templist 
               where !AccountTypeID.Conains(acc.AccountTypeId)
                       select acc).ToList();
```

---

### EDIT

No sure but you can try out

```
var orgdata= from org in foundOrgs
        select { OrgId =org.OrgId ,OrgName = org.OrgName , 
                 AccountTypes  = ( from acc in org.AccountTypes
                                  where !AccountTypeID.Conains(acc.AccountTypeId)
                                  select acc) };
```

---

Try something like this

```
var ids = {1, 2, 3};
  var query = from item in context.items
             where !ids.Contains( item.id )
             select item;
```

this will give you list of element which are not part of 1,2,3 i.e ids list , same you can apply in you code first find out which are not there and than remove it from the list

Image 
[image]